# Order of initialization for multiple declarators in a single declaration

Tags: c

Just looked through C99 and C11 trying to figure out whether they guarantee that multiple declarators in a single declaration are executed in order, from left to right. They do say that each full declarator ends in a sequence point

> **6.7.5<sub>C99</sub> Declarators**
>
> **6.7.6<sub>C11</sub> Declarators**
>
> **3** A full declarator is a declarator that is not part of another declarator. The end of a full declarator is a sequence point.[...]

but there seems to be nothing that would say that individual initializations are carried out in left-to-right order. Is it really unspecified or am I missing something simple?

```
int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int a = i++, b = i++;
  // Are values of `a` and `b` specified here?
}
```

If the order is unspecified, it outlaws the following implementation pattern

```
int array[N];
for (int *element = array, *element_end = element + N; 
     element != element_end; 
     ++element)
  *element = 0;
```

which strikes me as rather surprising. (I do realize that I can initialize `element_end` with `array + N` instead.)

P.S. C++ specification is not exactly explicit in that regard either. It has a footnote that says that `T d1, d2;` is equivalent to `T d1; T d2;`, but these are non-normative. Hence apparently the [DR#1342](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1342)

Comment: Perhaps related (I don't fully understand that sentence currently): C99 (n1256) 6.7.8 p23 _The order in which any side effects occur among the initialization list expressions is unspecified.(133)_ and C11 (n1570) 6.7.9 p23 _The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is
unspecified.(152)_; the footnote reads _In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order of subobject initialization._ for both drafts.

Comment: @mafso: I saw these statements, but they follow 6.7.8/12 (C99) which says "The rest of this subclause deals with initializers for objects that have aggregate or union type.". These statements are about individual initializers within a single aggregate initializer. It's a completely different story.

Comment: I see. Now the footnote makes sense to me.

Comment: @mafso, *initialization list* contain the subparts that are needed to initialize a compound, e.g a `struct` or an array. What we see here are separate declarators which have an initializer, each.

Comment: The magic word is sequence point, here. Sequence points order and separate evaluation in syntactical order if not specified otherwise.

Comment: @JensGustedt, sequence point seems not enough to me. `f() + g()` also has a sequence point after each function call (just as a full declarator has at its end). While the code is clearly not UB, I'm not sure whether it's possible that `a` is 1 and `b` is 0 here.

Comment: @mafso, the subtlety is in "if not specified otherwise". For expressions it is specified, 6.5 p3: *Except as specified
later, side effects and value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced.*

Comment: This question came up a few months ago but I can't find it now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how I missed it, considering that I actually searched the entire document for the word "order", but it is really there

> **6.8<sub>C99</sub> Statements and blocks**
>
> **3** A block allows a set of declarations and statements to be grouped into one syntactic unit.
> The initializers of objects that have automatic storage duration, and the variable length
> array declarators of ordinary identifiers with block scope, are evaluated and the values are
> stored in the objects (including storing an indeterminate value in objects without an
> initializer) each time the declaration is reached in the order of execution, as if it were a
> statement, **and within each declaration in the order that declarators appear**.

Comment: So to be completely clear `int i = 0;
  int a = i++, b = i++;` is defined and guaranteed to always produce a == 0, b == 1, and i == 2 ?

Comment: @2501: Yes, exactly.

Comment: for reference, in K&R 2nd edition, A.9.3 Compound Statement: *"Initialization of automatic objects is performed each time the block is entered at the top, and proceeds in the order of the declarators"*

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really unspecified or am I missing something simple?

The order is unspecified. This is because `,` in

```
 int a = i++, b = i++;
```

act as *separator*, not as an *operator*. The order of initialization is not guaranteed here.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Sequence points apply in syntactical order, unless explicitly specified otherwise. With your argument you wouldn't be able to say that side effects separated by `;` appear in a specific order. And BTW, the order must be specified, because in the initializor of `b`, `a` could be used as subexpression.

Comment: @JensGustedt; `a` could be used as subexpression may be because of unspecified order of initialization. There may be a case in which compiler through an error for `a` to be undeclared in `int a = i++, b = a + i++;`

Answer (score -2):

So here it is. if the initial value is supposedly 0, then a will be assigned the value: 1.
B will be also assigned 1 because the value of i hasn't changed. At this stage the values of a and b are assigned.

You may check by printf statement.
the a= i++ means that the value of a is i+1.

Just like that b is also given i+1.

Comment: That it sets `a` and `b` to particular values in your compiler, or in all compilers, does not mean that it is defined according to the C standard. The question is not about what values `int a = i++, b = i++;` sets `a` and `b` to but whether it is defined at all (many syntactically correct C programs are not).

Comment: That's actually makes no sense at all. Firstly, in my example `++` is post-increment. `a=i++` does not mean that the value of `a` is `i+1`. I don't know where you got that idea. The result of post-increment is the old value of its operand, not the new one.  Secondly,the language specification, as stated above, explicitly requires a sequence point after each declaration. This means that regardless of how you slice it, it is not possible to obtain  identical values in `a` and `b` in my example. If your compiler gave you such weird results, you compiler is seriously broken.

Comment: try in a compilerdoing it :)

Comment: @Fahad Rana: I'm sure everybody tried doing it in a compiler many times. No compiler I have ever seen behaves as you describe it in your answer. Would you please enlighten me as to what specific compiler allowed you to observe that highly unusual outcome for the above code?